# STA-Thread - Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I've got a thread having a print-job which creates a View and it's ViewModel and initializes them.

#### Without the thread:

The ViewModel has some bindings and is correctly initialized after giving it to the View.

```
//MyView : UserControl
//Constructor
DataContext = vm;
InitializeComponent();
```

#### With the thread:

During `InitializeComponent()` an exception is thrown.

I already checked answers on here and Google'd for it and found only the "usual" error - not running the thread in STA. This does not seem to apply for my code.

```
//Join thread if valid
//set to null
PrintThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecutePrintJob));
PrintThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
PrintThread.Start(); //Takes parameter but unused at the moment
```

```
//Translated it
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Line number "25" und Line position "43" from "An exception occured during the initialization of "System.Windows.Controls.Label.".
```

```
<Label  Content="TextBox --->"
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

What could possibly throw an `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` when using this inside another thread (not a task) ? I'm not sure how I can fix this issue, already asked a few people.

Comment: As far as I know using ui components requires you to be in the ui thread of the application. If your working with Windows.Forms look at the Invoke method on the Control and with wpf at the Dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at the exception the component you're using for printing would use a "System.Windows.Controls.Label" that is a UI component, therefore it should be instantiated on the main UI thread. I would try marshalling the call on that thread. I run in a maybe similar issue (even if in a different context) and I posted my solution here, I hope it helps:

[Why WPF button's command's CanExecute method is not called even if I call CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671287/why-wpf-buttons-commands-canexecute-method-is-not-called-even-if-i-call-comman/33671288#33671288)